# Insert data while @@rowcount>0

Tags: sql-server

I need to insert mass data between the same table on different databases. I would like to use `while`, `@@rowcount`, `insert`. This inserts only the first 10 rows (there are millions of rows in the source table). Any ideas?

```
DECLARE @date datatime 
SET @date = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

SET @date = @date 
WHILE @@ROWCOUNT > 0
BEGIN
INSERT TOP (10) db2.dbo.tbl2 
select * FROM db1.dbo.tbl1
where coldate < @date
END

(10 row(s) affected)

(0 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: Is that the complete code?

Comment: Easiest way would probably be http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/68280/3690

Comment: @SeanLange I think that is to trick the RowCount into being 1 to get into the loop in the first place

Comment: @Ghost - But `SET @date = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` would do that then.

Comment: @MartinSmith True, but their code sample is obviously incomplete and inaccurate. So it's possible they are doing things in between that could cause the rowcount to be 0.

Answer (score 0):

You could always try to break down the source data into monthly batches, like so-

```
DECLARE @date datatime 
SET @date = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
DECLARE @i int = 0;

WHILE @@ROWCOUNT > 0
BEGIN
SET @date = dateadd(mm, @i, @date)

INSERT INTO db2.dbo.tbl2 
select * FROM db1.dbo.tbl1
where month(coldate) = month(@date)
and year(coldate) = year(@date)

SET @i = @i + 1
END
```

Comment: yes, I would like to insert all data, '10' just an example, how many rows inserting at one loop

Comment: @LilyXO yes, but then you'd need additional `WHERE`-conditions to verify those rows dont already exist in tbl2, seems to me you're trying to insert the same top 10 rows in each iteration...

Comment: datetime column has over 2 years of data(with different date stamps)

Comment: why are you trying to insert the data in batches of 10, instead of just inserting all the data at once?

Comment: @iliketocode I've had to do this when there was so much data the server would run out of memory.

Comment: @ghost in that case the new code I posted should break down into monthly batches

Comment: thank you for the comments!! I'll try break down into monthly batches instead

Comment: @LilyXO NP, see my revised code for an example of this

Answer (score 0):

IF you have any IDENTITY column in table then you can add condition of batch of 1 million at a time. Otherwise you can create batch of 1 million, select TOP 1 million to  insert from Table of first db to table of 2nd Db WITH "NOT IN" in where clause from 2nd db table.